# How to implement tracking for create-new-post process in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a page on which users add posts. Adding a post is a 2-step process provided in 2 modals.

I already track some events with GA. Now, I would like to track the create-post process in order to know how many users finish it, how many don't (and if so, it's crucial for me to know at which step did they break the process). Like this:

1. **(start action)** User clicks "Create new post" button
2. **(intermediate step)** User clicks on "Continue" button in the first
   modal
3. **(end action)** User clicks on "Post now" button in the second modal

Can I do this with GA? Should I use E-commerce tracking to achieve what I need?

Comment: E-Commerce sounds like overkill - why not track the modals as virtual pageviews, set up the final step as goal and use a funnel ?

Comment: Sounds nice. I didn't know I can track modals as pageviews. Now, when I try ti create a test goal, I don't have a way to set up steps (funnel?) leading to the goal. Did you figure this stuff out alone or there's docs I could take a look at?

Comment: If you use a destination goal you can check the "use funnel" option. For the other thing google "virtual pageviews" (I'll try to make this into a complete answer later in the day).

Comment: That would be really cool. I appreciate it. Will look it up, of course.